# sparse matrix overdetermined linear equation system c/c++ library

Tags: c++, equation, algebra, sparse-matrix

I need a library to solve Ax=b systems, where A is a non-symmetric sparse matrix, with 8 entry per row (and it might be quite big). I think a library that implements biconjugate gradient should be fine, but i can't find one that works (i've tried iml++, but there are some headers missing in the iml++/sparselib++ packages). Any tips?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm?

Comment: yep, but i think ublas is just a template library, i can't see any iterative method to solve sparse systems, am i wrong?

Comment: There is a sparse matrix class.  I haven't looked in any great detail at whether or not there is a solver for it, but you might want to look at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm to see if there's something in there you can use.

Comment: yes i've already read that page, but i doubt there's any solver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are standard ways of treating overdetermined systems. For example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_equations) says this:

> A set of linear simultaneous equations can be written in matrix form as Ax = y. If there are more equations than variables, the system is called overdetermined, and has (in general) no solutions. The system can then be changed to (A<sup>T</sup>A)x = A<sup>T</sup>y. The new system has as many equations as variables (the matrix A<sup>T</sup>A is a square matrix) and can be solved in the usual way. The solution is a least-squares solution of the original, overdetermined system, minimizing the Euclidean norm ||Ax − y||, a measure of the discrepancy between the two sides in the original system.

Therefore you can use any standard square matrix sparse solver.

Personally I use a direct solver from [CSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/CSparse/) by Tim Davis. Tim has written a number of excellent direct sparse solvers. Indeed, his [UMFPACK](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/umfpack/) is another excellent option and is used by MATLAB, for example. Note that both of these solvers offer C interfaces. If you are looking for something with a native C++ interface then I have nothing to offer.

I have had some experience with iterative solvers. However, I have found that for the problems I was looking at, the iterative methods became unstable for large matrices. I have had much more success with direct solvers. Of course, it's perfectly plausible that you could have the reverse experience depending on the type of matrix your problem throws up.

Comment: thank you very much, this has been helpful, i'm using umfpack right now (it was quite annoying making a visual studio project to compile it :D), it seems to work fine

Comment: but, one more question.. given A, how can i solve A^tAx = A^tb using umfpack? i mean, does umfpack give me a way to compute A^tA and A^tb or i've to multiply on my own? (with A^t, i mean transposed A)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the UMFPACK routines. As I said I use `CSparse` because, paradoxically, the simplest algorithms seem to perform best for my problems. But I believe you need to form A^tA and A^tb yourself. Certainly CSparse has routines to do those products. I would expect UMFPACK to do also.

Comment: i'm now using eigen's (http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) bindings for umfpack, that implements some operations on sparse matrices i need, and allows me to call umfpack functions with a clean interface, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [ARPACK](http://www.caam.rice.edu/software/ARPACK/) solves sparse nonsymetric matrix problems.  There is a C++ version

Comment: ARPACK is an eigen solver. It is magnificent at that but the question concerns a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

To David Heffernan's answer: Do not forget one important thing: matrix A must be checked/proved to have linearly independent columns, otherwise it could happen that (A^T A) is singular (and then it would not work, of course).