# is it ok to access value(entry in thread safe map) pointed by pointer inside non-thread safe container?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, boost-thread

For example,

```
// I am using thread safe map from
// code.google.com/p/thread-safe-stl-containers
#include <thread_safe_map.h>

class B{
  vector<int> b1;
};

//Thread safe map
thread_safe::map<int, B> A;
B b_object;
A[1] = b_object;

// Non thread safe map.
map<int, B*> C;
C[1] = &A[1].second;
```

So are following operations still thread safe?

```
Thread1:
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
  cout << C[1]->b1[i];
}

Thread2:
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
  C[1]->b1.push_back(i);
}
```

Is there any problem in the above code? If so how can I fix it?

Is it OK to access value(entry in thread safe map) pointed by pointer inside non-thread safe container?

Comment: You are changing a vector in one thread and reading it in another: this leads to  havoc.

Comment: @JohanvanBreda, Thanks. But that vector resides in thread-safe map A. How it is going to create a problem ? I am very weak at multi-threading, please explain bit more.

Comment: The immediate problem I see with this is if `C[1]` did not exist before or if either threads is modifying the structure of `C` (adding/removing elements) you have a problem there.

Comment: I think a lot depends on what `thread_safe_map` is and how it implements its thread safety tbh.

Comment: @Galik, Thanks. Assume that C[1] exists before threads start running. And look for any other issue ?

Comment: I assume the thread-safe map can handle changes to itself: inserting and removing key-value pairs.  I assume it has a mutex that takes care of this.  There is no protection for the  change of the vector though - the map has nothing to do with that.

Comment: The only way I think this could be safe is if `thread_safe_map` returns some kind of *locked proxy* object rather than a reference for its `C[]` operator. Regardless, "thread safe" containers a pretty inefficient for many uses.

Comment: @JohanvanBreda, Thanks I agree with you. But I did not get 'There is no protection for the change of the vector though - the map has nothing to do with that.'. Little confusing. Did you mean we don't have protection while accessing pointer from C, but there is a protection when accessing value from the pointer which is in A ?

Comment: Yeah that just returns a bare `T&` which is not safe. For a safe (though poorly tested) alternative you can consider this:  https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/924

Comment: @Galik, Thanks . Did you paste wrong link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939649/sparse-matrix-overdetermined-linear-equation-system-c-c-library ? How it is related to this question?

Comment: @jpb123 Ooops sorry, I updated the link

Comment: @Galik, Very useful link. Thanks a lot. Reading it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you are doing there is not safe. The way your `thread_safe_map` is implemented is to take a lock for the duration of every function call:

```
//Element Access
T & operator[]( const Key & x ) { boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock( mutex ); return storage[x]; }
```

The lock is released as soon as the access function ends which means that any modification you make through the returned reference has no protection.

As well as being not entirely safe this method is very slow.

A safe(er), efficient, but highly experimental way to lock containers is proposed here: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/issues/924 
 with source code here https://github.com/galik/GSL/blob/lockable-objects/include/gsl/gsl_lockable (shameless self promotion disclaimer).

Answer (score 2):

In general, STL containers can be accessed from multiple threads as long as all threads either:

- read from the same container
- modify *elements* in a thread safe manner

You cannot `push_back` (or `erase`, `insert`, etc.) from one thread and read from another thread. Suppose that you are trying to access an element in thread 1 while `push_back` in thread 2 is in the middle of reallocation of vector's storage. This might crash the application, might return garbage (or might work, if you're lucky).

The second bullet point applies to situations like this:

```
std::vector<std::atomic_int> elements;

// Thread 1:
elements[10].store(5);

// Thread 2:
int v = elements[10].load();
```

In this case, you're concurrently reading and writing an atomic variable, but the vector itself is not modified - only its element is.

**Edit:** using `thread_safe::map` doesn't change anything in you're case. While the modifying the map is ok, modifying its elements is not. Putting `std::vector` in a thread-safe collection doesn't automagically make it thread-safe too.

Comment: Thanks. What if instead of vector we have some simple struct(int x, int y). ? Then modifying and accessing this struct from thread_safe::map is safe right ?

Comment: Unfortunate no, you would change a reference to a struct instead of a reference to a vector. As soon as you retrieve a reference to a value from your map, it works as if you did not had the map in the first place: changing this value is not thread safe by itself.

Comment: In case of a struct, there's another problem. Reads and write are not atomic, so it might happen that when multiple threads modify an element, some changes will be lost. Also, changes might not be (immediately) visible to other threads, depending on CPU architecture and code generated by compiler. For this reason, I've used `std::atomic_int` in my example. Using `struct` here will be unsafe, but in a different way (e. g. it won't crash your application).